# KheperaIV Test File is more complicated than I expected

Tags: c++, c, robotics

I am working on an undergrad project involving the Khepera IV mobile robot, and as I'm reading the files that came with it, I came across this line that confuses me:

```
for (i=0;i<5;i++) {
    usvalues[i] = (short)(Buffer[i*2] | Buffer[i*2+1]<<8);
...
```

From the same file, usvalues[i] is initialized as usvalues[5] for each of the ultrasonic sensors on the robot, Buffer[] is initialized as Buffer[100] i assume for the sample rate of the ultrasonic sensors. But I've never seen a variable set like this. Can someone help me to understand this?

Comment: The line of code posted appears to be building 16-bit values from an array of 8-bit values, taken in little-endian pairs.

Comment: Look at this list of operators : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic. You will find `|` is bitwise or and `<<` is shift left. It is an efficient way to calculate 16 bit values from an 8bit buffer (little endian as Weather Vane said). The cast in C++ should be a static_cast<short> though not the "C" style cast (short) though.

Answer (score 1):

Code reads the `Buffer[]` array (certainly it has 8-bit elements) 2 successive bytes per iteration in little endian order (lower addressed byte is the least significant byte).  It then forms a 16-bit value to save in `usvalues[]`.

```
for (i=0;i<5;i++) {
  usvalues[i] = (short)(Buffer[i*2] | Buffer[i*2+1]<<8);
```

---

Code should use `uint8_t Buffer[100];` to prevent doing a *signed* left shift.

`usvalues[]` better as some *unsigned* type like `uint16_t` or `unsigned` and use *unsigned* operations.

```
uint8_t Buffer[100];
uint16_t /* or unsigned */ usvalues[5 /* or more */];

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  usvalues[i] = Buffer[i*2] | (unsigned)Buffer[i*2+1] << 8;
}
```